# Is 208V 3phase enough to supply a 220-240V UPS?

Tags: ups, voltage

Our input voltage is *208V 3-phase* but we are not certain if it's capable of powering a *220-240V APC UPS*. Can this power supply be used with this input voltage?

Comment: unclear what you are asking

Comment: Is 208V 3phase enough to supply a 220-240V UPS?

Comment: if its not clear to you..its ok..dont mind...thanks.

Comment: I invite you to check http://superuser.com:8080/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: ok...thanks for the info..ill take note of this next time.

Comment: Are you really planning on supply your electronic equipment using 4 wires, 3 hots and one ground?  If not, take the "three phase" wording out of your question.  If you only use 2 hots and a ground your equipment is probably supplied by a single phase of three.

Answer (score 3):

A regular consumer-grade USV is driven by a single phase. So no, that’s not possible.

A single phase of your 3-phase 208v provides ~120 Volt, which is the standard mains voltage only in North America, some parts of South America, & Japan.
Almost everywhere else uses 220 - 240v, for which it would not be suitable.

Answer (score -1):

I assume you are NOT talking about using all three phases (4 wires, 3 hot, 1 ground) and you are talking about using the voltage across two of the phases which is seen as single phase 208.  If so you are NOT using three phase 208 for supply.

[image]

[image]

Either way I would contact the manufacturer to verify if their equipment will work at 208VAC if it is not printed in their documentation.  With electronics it could go either way.  Motors and light bulbs and such usually don't care 208 vs 220.

Most systems like this have a neutral that would give you 120 volts hot to neutral meaning "normal" USA voltages.  I would recommend you just use the neutral and one of the phases to run things at 120 volts.